# How to profile MySQL during a period of time

Tags: mysql, profiler

I want to know during the execution of `sysbench --time=100 ...`, the bottleneck (function) of MySQL. So I want to profile MySQL when executing `sysbench --time=100 ...`.

I know by `set profiling = 1;`, I can get such profile for a specific query, but not for a period of time (100 seconds). What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Profiling is virtually useless.  Use the slowlog:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog  And you can do that on a live system without bothering with sysbench.

Comment: @RickJames  OK - so what is profiling good for? Timings? AFAIK, it's being deprecated - what's going to be in its place?

Comment: After exhausting indexing and tuning options there is [using perf](https://www.percona.com/community-blog/2020/02/05/finding-mysql-scaling-problems-using-perf/) to profile the internal workings of MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, `PROFILE` always said that 99% of the time was spent in some "useless"  category, such as "sending data".  Such categories 'never' translated into anything actionable.  `PROFILE` is being deprecated -- good riddance.

`EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON ...` have some use.  So does the "optimizer trace".

Use the slowlog: mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog And you can do that on a live system.

Another technique for looking into what is going on is with the "Handler" counts.  This works even when a table is [currently] so small that timings are not very useful.  Details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Answer (score 1):

MySQL query profiling is being deprecated in favor of a performance_schema solution.

The query profiler gives you latencies for each "stage" of query execution for a given query in your current session.

The performance schema gives you latencies for each stage of query execution across many sessions, not just your current session. You can basically get profiled queries for all queries in a span of time, like you asked.

Unfortunately, navigating the performance schema is complex. It's a very powerful feature, but not much work has been done to make it user-friendly.